# Not admin anymore after changing username on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: administrator, password-recovery, macos-highsierra

I've changed my username and now I'm unable to do admin stuff. No `sudo`, no system preferences `unlock` work.

I've managed to:

1. start in single user mode
2. open a terminal
3. chroot into my system

As this is not a Linux I'm not sure where to change stuff...
How to fix this ridiculous mistake?

Comment: What method did you use to change your username?  How many users did you have before?  Were you reusing a username?  Were you using 'root' or any other protected names?

Comment: As far as I remember, I did it in the system prefs panel. Can't remember, but probably 1 user. Can't remember. Of course not. See my answer below, I did fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution based on [this](https://www.lifewire.com/create-new-admin-account-for-login-issues-2259976). Few things I did differently:

- instead of `/sbin/mount -uw /` use `chroot /Volumes/<yours>`
- instead of `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone` do `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

In nutshell:

1. boot into recovery mode
2. open terminal
3. execute `chroot /Volumes/<yours>`
4. execute `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` - after reboot, it'll make MacOS think it is a new setup, so that you'll be redirected to the post-install screen where you can create a new admin user
5. reboot
6. follow steps
7. update your old user with the newly created one